# Making another object with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

First question so sorry if somethings out of place.

Below is a code snippet that works just fine.

Init function

```
    ShaderLoader shaderloader;
    Program = shaderloader.LoadShaders("VertexShader.vs", "FragmentShader.fs");
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexBufferData) * 
    vertexBufferData.size(), &vertexBufferData.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Render function

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glUseProgram(Program);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glutSwapBuffers();
```

This all works fine within my main.cpp but when i put this into a class it gives me an access violation error. My class container holds its own VertexArrayObject and VertexBuffer so I am assuming that should be enough information to draw a simple triangle as it draws fine when it is not in a class. My end goal here is to create two objects so if I'm going about this completely wrong please point me in the right direction!

Code in the sprite class:

```
    void Mesh::init(std::vector<GLfloat> vertexBufferData)
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayObject);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VertexArrayObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexBufferData) *         
        vertexBufferData.size(), &vertexBufferData.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void Mesh::Draw()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

How I'm using the class in the main.cpp:

```
    Mesh object1;

    void init()
    {
        ShaderLoader shaderloader;
        Program = shaderloader.LoadShaders("VertexShader.vs", "FragmentShader.fs");
        object1.init(vertexBufferData);
    }

    void Render()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glUseProgram(Program);
        object1.Draw();
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
```

And the exception thrown is: 0x5253F00A

Access Violation reading location

Comment: please post the error message and the code where you actually put it into a class.

Comment: Edited. Sorry about that!

Comment: Why are you passing the vertex buffer data by value?

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean why not?

Comment: I've tried passing in by reference before but I understand it to simply be points that I want a triangle to use so passing in by value shouldn't make a difference should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Mesh` class (opposed to the code at the top) writes twice to the same variable. Was that a simple typo?

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayObject);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexArrayObject);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Well how about that...
Could you verify one thing for me though? I also made this mistake when I had all of it in the main, so why is it that it worked there?

Comment: @Vishuu could've been a coincididence. The names for OpenGL objects are typically integers increasing with every new name. So the actual values you'll end up with in `VertexArrayObject`/`VertexBuffer` could be both `1`s, and for some reason that has changed. There's a multitude of ways a bad usage of OpenGL can go bad or, which is even worse, pretend to work fine.